# sql joins to fetch data from different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

how to write a query to fetch the data (*provider name, service name,location name*) from appointment table which has foreign key *sechedule_id(f.k)* of schedule table.
schedule table in turn has foreign key *Provider_id (f.k),Serviceid(f.k),Location id (f.k)*

```
**appointment table**
Appointment_id char(23)
schedule id char(23) (f.k)

**schedule table**
Schedule id (p.k)
Provider_id (f.k)
Service id (f.k)
Location id (f.k)
Availability

**service table**
Service_id(p.k) 
Name

**provider table**
Provider_id(p.k)
Provider name


**location table**
Location_id(p.k)
Location_name
```

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result. Also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You should not post your assignment here. If you are facing any problem in code then post your code and we will provide your ans.
but i give you the ans for this queation.

```
select p.provider_name,s.name,l.location_name from appointment a,schedule sc,service s,provider p,location l where
sc.schedule_id=a.schedule_id and
sc.provider_id=p.provider_id and
sc.service_id=s.service_id and
sc.location_id=l.location_id and
a.appointment_id = 'Your id'
```

Hope it will help.